# How To Retrieve Data From Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I Have Cassandra Column Family Name as Data3, In That I Have 2 Columns With Data As Follows

```
URL                           Data 
www.google.com               Google
```

I Want A Similar Query in Cassandra like ( `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Data='Google'`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select * from Data3 where Data = 'Google'
```

This is CQL, as described by [CQL Language Reference](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/index) on DataStax.

Weirdly, that we use earlier version of Cassandra where CQL was not supported. And we never thought that we actually required something like SQL. If you wanted more detailed read these articles

1. [CQL Utility](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/test-driving-the-new-cql-utility)
2. [You could query without SQL type utility](http://maxgrinev.com/2010/07/12/do-you-really-need-sql-to-do-it-all-in-cassandra/)
3. You could see non-SQL example/tutorial [here](https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-tutorial) . [Here](https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorial/GetSliceForAreaCodeCity.java) is how you select columns